# In Kotlin, can I have a conditional builder element on a collection?

Tags: kotlin, oop

Currently I have a query that looks something like this:

```
override suspend fun getExternalTestsForProfile(profileKey: String, take: Int?): List<ExternalTestEntity> {
        RealmDb.useRealm {
            where(RealmExternalTest::class.java)
                .sort(RealmExternalTestFields.CREATED_AT, Sort.DESCENDING)
                .findAll()
```

I want to have functionality so that if `take` is null, it will fetch all elements in the collection, but if an Int is supplied, it will take and map in that case only.

So my "desired" functionality is something like this:

```
    override suspend fun getExternalTestsForProfile(profileKey: String, take: Int?): List<ExternalTestEntity> {
        RealmDb.useRealm {
            where(RealmExternalTest::class.java)
                .sort(RealmExternalTestFields.CREATED_AT, Sort.DESCENDING)
                .findAll()
                if (take != null) {
                    .take(3)
                } else {
                    // Do not apply a .take
                }
                .map { realmExternalTest -> realmExternalTest.toExternalTestEntity() }
```

I want the take to happen before the mapping because the mapping may be expensive, because it can have a ton of elements. So doing the expensive map operation only to take 3 elements is wasteful.

I considered overloading `getExternalTestsForProfile` to have one with a `take` and one without, but was hoping I could sort of combine it since the only real difference here is how many elements are mapped and returned out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Realm, but [looking at their API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/examples/filter-data/) it looks like `take` is not what you want here. You should instead [limit()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/java/latest/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#limit(long)) before you even call `findAll()`, otherwise `findAll()` would return all results.

Now to your actual question, whether you stick with `take` or use `limit`, you can use `let` to perform this operation inline:

```kotlin
where(RealmExternalTest::class.java)
    .sort(RealmExternalTestFields.CREATED_AT, Sort.DESCENDING)
    .let {
        if (take != null) it.limit(take) else it
    }
    .findAll()
```

Or you could extract this into a function for better readability:

```kotlin
private fun <E> RealmQuery<E>.maybeLimit(limit: Long?): RealmQuery<E> =
    if (limit != null) limit(limit) else this
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and you are right, limit would be better here as well. Thank you so much.